# how to set the previous date become inactive in UI dtaepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have downloaded the UI date picker with the theme start theme. I have implemented this in my site. Butt I want to stop by selecting the previous date from the calendar. I.e. the previous date must be inactive. I don't know the jquery. So please tell me how to do this?
See my code

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    inline: true

                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*demo page css*/
            body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
            .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
            #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
            #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
            ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
            ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
        </style>
```

In side the body

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   // Datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
         minDate: 0 
      });
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/pwGT9/

Answer (score 0):

You can just [restrict the date range](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max).

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn7km/